# iOS Build Error Using Quickblox Pod file in AWS Mobile SDK

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, quickblox, aws-sdk

We have an iOS application that is referencing the AWS Mobile frameworks directly and several other libraries using CocoaPods. The project builds fine

But, when we add the 'Quickblox-SDK' as an additional library to reference in the PodFile and run pod install I get several build/linker errors:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_AWSSNSErrorDomain", referenced from:
      ___88-[AWSPushManager interceptApplication:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:]_block_invoke.239 in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNS", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSGetEndpointAttributesInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSSetEndpointAttributesInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSSubscribeInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSUnsubscribeInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAccessToken", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKGraphRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKLoginManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDSignIn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSGoogleSignInProvider.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

If we remove the $(inherited) flag from the Other Linker Flags build setting, getting below errors:-

bash: /User/..../AWSCore.framework/strip-frameworks.sh: No such file or directory
uploadDSYM[13005:219405] Fabric.framework/run 1.4.1 (160)
uploadDSYM[13005:219405] Launched uploader in validation mode
bash: /Users/..../Frameworks/Quickblox.framework/strip-framework.sh: No such file or directory

Any Help will be appreciated..

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `Pods-{PROJECT_NAME}.debug.xcconfig` and `Pods-{PROJECT_NAME}.release.xcconfig` file, find this line

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"z" ....
```

and remove the **-ObjC**

Alternatively, you can also fix this from XCode by going to Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags, and remove **-ObjC** from there
[image]